# The infamous TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json

I have been searching for the past few days and although I have a better understanding of the error, I still don't have a full solution.  I have a json responce below, that I am trying to print just the tones in emotion_tone. The value of 'data' is a JSON response copied below

My loop:

```
for key in data.keys():
doc_tone = data[key]['tone_categories'][0]['tones']
for tones in doc_tone:
    print (tones)
```

The code above returns the following

```
{u'tone_name': u'Anger', u'score': 0.105542, u'tone_id': u'anger'}
{u'tone_name': u'Disgust', u'score': 0.134394, u'tone_id': u'disgust'}
{u'tone_name': u'Fear', u'score': 0.150116, u'tone_id': u'fear'}
{u'tone_name': u'Joy', u'score': 0.083824, u'tone_id': u'joy'}
{u'tone_name': u'Sadness', u'score': 0.605555, u'tone_id': u'sadness'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 5.py", line 21, in <module>
  doc_tone = data[key]['tone_categories'][0]['tones']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how to fix the error.  I have search a bunch but I can figure it out. I know the error is caused by a list when a index is expected, can someone please help, this is driving me crazy!

In short I would like to return a list of tones, from a tone_category, so I can write to a csv file. Essentially my response minus the error

here is the json response sample contained the variable `data`

```
{
"document_tone": {
"tone_categories": [
  {
    "tones": [
      {
        "score": 0.105542,
        "tone_id": "anger",
        "tone_name": "Anger"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.134394,
        "tone_id": "disgust",
        "tone_name": "Disgust"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.150116,
        "tone_id": "fear",
        "tone_name": "Fear"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.083824,
        "tone_id": "joy",
        "tone_name": "Joy"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.605555,
        "tone_id": "sadness",
        "tone_name": "Sadness"
      }
    ],
    "category_id": "emotion_tone",
    "category_name": "Emotion Tone"
  },
  {
    "tones": [
      {
        "score": 0,
        "tone_id": "analytical",
        "tone_name": "Analytical"
      },
      {
        "score": 0,
        "tone_id": "confident",
        "tone_name": "Confident"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.966403,
        "tone_id": "tentative",
        "tone_name": "Tentative"
      }
    ],
    "category_id": "language_tone",
    "category_name": "Language Tone"
  },
  {
    "tones": [
      {
        "score": 0.915827,
        "tone_id": "openness_big5",
        "tone_name": "Openness"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.064387,
        "tone_id": "conscientiousness_big5",
        "tone_name": "Conscientiousness"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.375757,
        "tone_id": "extraversion_big5",
        "tone_name": "Extraversion"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.579473,
        "tone_id": "agreeableness_big5",
        "tone_name": "Agreeableness"
      },
      {
        "score": 0.287825,
        "tone_id": "emotional_range_big5",
        "tone_name": "Emotional Range"
      }
    ],
    "category_id": "social_tone",
    "category_name": "Social Tone"
  }
```

I appreciate any help you guys can provide.
Thanks

Comment: cannot reproduce. Works fine here (adding `]}}`) to complete your data struct (well you also have to fix your indentation)

Comment: There's something wrong with your data

Comment: I'm guessing there is more then a single key in the actual data? Since the one key in your's works fine so the program must be crashing on a different key and since you are missing close braces in the json it seems likely there is more to it.

Comment: Hello everyone thanks for helping.  I must have not copied the complete json response .  When I tried to paste ti I receive the "too long by 6710 characters"

Comment: Incomplete JSON file... but it works just fine when `] } }` is added at the end. Could you post the whole of your code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in formating. You opened two `[` but only closed one, which made the loop try to apply the operation on this:

`"category_id": "language_tone",
    "category_name": "Language Tone"`
Close that bracket before this lines,and it should work.

Comment: I don't believe the error caused by that...if it is, it would be a syntax error instead

Comment: @abccd not exactly. The interpreter raise the first mistake it finds. In this case,it as a TypeError.

Comment: It's interesting to point that the code actually runs till `sadness`, meaning the problem is on the loop going too deep in the data.

Comment: I walked thru the code and all the brackets and paired. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the issue was associated with he way I was trying to loop thru the  json in different "categories".  Once that category was specifies I was able to return the data without any issues. code below:

```
for key in data:
if key == 'document_tone':
    for tones in data['document_tone']:         
        doc_tone = data[key]['tone_categories'][0]['tones']
        for tones in doc_tone:
            print (tones)
```

The results below:

```
{u'tone_name': u'Anger', u'score': 0.089058, u'tone_id': u'anger'}
{u'tone_name': u'Disgust', u'score': 0.050212, u'tone_id': u'disgust'}
{u'tone_name': u'Fear', u'score': 0.607714, u'tone_id': u'fear'}
{u'tone_name': u'Joy', u'score': 0.17284, u'tone_id': u'joy'}
{u'tone_name': u'Sadness', u'score': 0.142486, u'tone_id': u'sadness'}
```

Thanks guys I appreciate your help!